# How to preventDefault() in HostListener Input action

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-directive

Im trying to write a directive that limit user to input numeric only characters in the input text control.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[numericControl]'
})
export class NumericControlDirective {

    contructor(
        private el: ElementRef,
    ) {}

    @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
    onInput(e: any) {
        if (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }

}
```

Usage

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Volume" numericControl />
```

But it doesn't work, Anyone came across this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use Keyboard event type - `keydown` or `keypress`:

```
@HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
onInput(e: any) {
  if (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) {
      e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Comment: you can also use `input[type=number]` on your case :) who is much better because will show only numeric keyboard on mobile / tablet.

Comment: @popStart keydown prevents me even from arrow keys, backspace and delete so i change it to `keypress` your idea still works great

Comment: @Yanis-git yes, thanks a lot but it is not in my case :)

Comment: i get it, nice to see you have find your solution here :) happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
@HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(event) {
    let e = <KeyboardEvent>event;
    if (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```