# How to prevent any keyboard events and their default behavior on element in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-event-emitter

I am trying do prevent any keyboard activity on Angular Mat Header. I want to block keyboard navigation, entering steps using header. I want to use buttons only
How to stop any keyboard activity on that element as preventDefault() does not work.

```
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('mat-step-
    header').addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {

      // What should go here?

    });
}
```

Comment: have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50022255/how-to-preventdefault-in-hostlistener-input-action)

Comment: I believe Hostlistener listens to window, document and body element. How can I taget specific element by <mat-step-header>?

Comment: You could try using a directive directly on the material component, also using event.stopPropagation() should do the trick [like this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/directivestopropagation?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

Comment: I would like to avoid touching material component as it is part of modules and is used in other places as well.